# How can I perform Boolean comparisons on variables exported from an onClick toggle?

Tags: android, variables, global, local

I have set up two toggle buttons to change the value of two global variables (hopefully). I would now like to perform Boolean comparisons of the global variable values. Should I do this in another method and if so how? I am having trouble with the next step.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class NewActivity1 extends Activity{

public static int exportNumber1;
public static int exportNumber2;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_activity1);

    final ToggleButton atb1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    atb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int x = 0;

            if (atb1.isChecked())
            {
                x = 1;
            }
            else{}
            exportNumber1 = x;
            }
        }
    );

    final ToggleButton atb2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);  
    atb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int y = 0;

            if (atb2.isChecked())
            {
                y = 1;
            }
            else{}
            exportNumber2 = y;

    }
});


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace onCLickListener with setOnCheckedChangeListener method.

```
atb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int x = 0;

        if (isChecked)
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        exportNumber1 = x;
            }
        });
```

// Updated Your code with changes as mentioned above.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class NewActivity1 extends Activity{

public static int exportNumber1;
public static int exportNumber2;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_activity1);

    final ToggleButton atb1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
   atb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int x = 0;

        if (isChecked)
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        exportNumber1 = x;
            }
        });


    final ToggleButton atb2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);  
    atb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int y = 0;

        if (isChecked)
        {
            y = 1;
        }
        exportNumber2 = 1;
            }
        });   

}

}
```

Comment: Just for reference, because I didn't test it, is that because the onClick fires before isChecked gets changed, and thus he's reading the previous value?

Comment: OK, so after I replace my code with prem's code how do I set up my comparisons of the globals?

Comment: What do you mean by comparison of global ?

Comment: Well. I want to store local variables (0 for not clicked and 1 for clicked) in global variables because I would aftewards like carry out, for example, the following computation. if (exportNumber1 == exportNumber2) {print something) else {print something else}

Comment: Does it? Well OK. Ill give it a blast prem.

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify it greatly by doing:

```
exportNumber1=atb1.isChecked()?1:0;
```

it's the same as this but in one line

```
int x = 0;

        if (atb1.isChecked())
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        else{}
        exportNumber1 = x;
        }
```